# How to remove Python 3 from Fedora 27 workstation completely?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fedora

Actually I tampered certain libraries of Python 3 and they stopped working, so I want to remove complete Python 3 and reinstall it.
When I ran this command:

```
sudo dnf remove python3
```

the result was:

```
Error: 
 Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: dnf
```

Please suggest me how to remove python3 and reinstall without any dependencies.

Previously I had the same issue with python I ran the same commands and it successfully removed it and then when I installed the same, It installed without any dependent libraries.

I googled and read but didn't find any relevant answers.

Comment: That error message suggests that Python is required for the package manager to work, so you can't remove it. Does `dnf reinstall python3` work?

Comment: It reinstalled Python3 but its dependencies still existing.

Comment: you don't. Python3 is integrated into fedora.

Comment: You should just check DNF documentation on how to do a force reinstall of Python3, (and possibily of all Python related packages)

Answer (score 3):

It appears that `dnf` uses python internally. So removing it forcefully will break you package management, and then you are in a much worse situation.

You could remove all installed python packages like this, while still keeping python itself:

```
for package in $(pip3 freeze); do pip3 uninstall -y $package; done
```

If that doesn't help because the standard library of Python is broken then try

```
dnf reinstall python3 -y
```

Comment: What if few packages got `permission denied error`?

Comment: Yes, paste the entire first on into the terminal, if it doesn't solve your problem try the second one. Both might be run with `sudo`.

Comment: maybe trying jsut the reinstall part. "uninstalling" all Python packages won't work or help.