# Reinstall Python with python broken - bad interpreter (Linux Fedora)

Tags: python, linux, fedora

So I was messing around with different versions of python to the extent that now I cannot even do a `dnf reinstall python`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879993/how-to-remove-python-3-from-fedora-27-workstation-completely), and python does not work.
The error which appears on any command really is: `bash: /usr/bin/dnf: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: Permission denied`

I do have python3.7, python3.9, and python3.10 folders in /usr/lib which as far as I know are in somewhat good condition.

What can I do?

EDIT: my current /usr/bin/python3 points to a directory instead of an executable... could this be the problem?

`which python3` returns the following:

```
/usr/bin/which: no python3 in (/root/.local/bin:/root/bin:/home/dominik/.local/bin:/home/dominik/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin)
```

Comment: It's not fun, but you could install the required RPM's available from [koji](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=14310).  You'll need to install all the dependencies yourself.

Comment: I see python3-3.8.10-1.fc32 in koji but I need the one for Fedora 35... and would it automatically create the necessary symlinks in /usr/bin ?

Comment: I don't know which version you want/need, but [here's one](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=1931140).  Depending on the extent of your "messing around", you may need other packages/rpms, as well.  And yes, installing the rpm will create all the necessary directories, etc.

Comment: Thanks, a rpm -qpR installed the python3.8 command. Now I just have to connect /usr/bin/python to /usr/bin/python3.8 somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, it is important to download the exact rpm package that dnf is configured to use. This can be found by `rpm -qa python3`.

After finding and downloading this package, install it using the rpm -i command. A successful installation will create the /usr/bin/*python_version* folder. For me, it was python3.10, so /usr/bin/python3.10.

When this is done, remove the existing symlink at /usr/bin/python3, and instead link to the newly created python version.

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python3.10 /usr/bin/python3
```

dnf and python should now work.